# Unable to run Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator on Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-cli

I am trying to run an Android app made in Titanium Appcelerator, to run in Windows Phone emulator
I have VS 2013 Pro & Appcelerator Studio 4.5 
I wish to run app in Windows Phone emulator, but it gives me error

```
[ERROR] :  Invalid "--device-id" value "8-1-1"
For help, run: titanium.js help build
```

Command Details

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
  Version                     = 10.0.10586
  Architecture                = 32bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 8479367168

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 0.12.7
  npm Version                 = 2.11.3

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.6

Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.2.2.GA
  SDK Path                    = C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.2.2.GA
  Target Platform             = windows

Command
  c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe c:\Users\Test\.appcelerator\install\5.2.2\package\node_modules\titanium\lib\titanium.js build run -p windows -T ws-local --wp-sdk 10 --config-file C:\Users\Test\AppData\Loca
l\Temp\build-1462961770428.json --log-level info --no-banner --project-dir c:\Users\Test\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\TestProject
```

Also,
On running :

```
appc run -p windows -T ws-local --wp-sdk 8.1
```

I get :

What pfx file should sign the app? (leave blank to generate):

What will be your PFX password?:

Both of which I bypass with enter key.
Then I get a prompt to "Enter a Private Key Password" with "Key" as "Subject Key". Entering anything here gives

```
[ERROR] An error occurred during build after 4m 29s 170ms
[ERROR] Failed to create certificate (code 4294967295)
```

Also running :

```
appc run -p windows --target wp-emulator --deploy-time development --device-id 8-1-1
```

Gives :

```
2016-05-11T10:25:57.544Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
No Windows Phone emulators found
2016-05-11T10:25:57.562Z | ERROR  | No Windows Phone emulators found
```

> > Even though i have installed Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators

I have tried literally every possible solution...
Please help to run emulator

Answer (score 1):

Make sure windows phone sdk is installed and its path is added in studio. Make sure sdk and emulators are detected by studio. Add windows app publisher id also.Run command

```
appc info
```

In my system I get the following output in windows section.

```
Microsoft (R) Visual Studio
  14.0 (selected)
    Path                      = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\
    CLR Version               = v4.0.30319
    MSBuild Version           = v14.0.24730.2
    Windows Phone SDKs        = not installed

Microsoft (R) Windows Phone SDK
  8.1 (selected)
    Path                      = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\

Windows PowerShell
    Enabled                   = yes

Windows Phone Emulators
8.1
  Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB
    UDID                      8-1-1
  Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch
    UDID                      8-1-2
  Emulator 8.1 WXGA 4.5 inch 
    UDID                      8-1-3 
  Emulator 8.1 720P 4.7 inch 
    UDID                      8-1-4 
  Emulator 8.1 1080P 5.5 inch 
    UDID                      8-1-5 
  Emulator 8.1 1080P 6 inch 
    UDID                      8-1-6 
10.0 

Windows Phone Devices 
  Device 
    UDID                      0
```

If you find everything ok in your system try running the following command.

```
appc run -p windows -T wp-emulator
```

Comment: Thanks Saeed
Mine says : 
Microsoft (R) Visual Studio
  12.0 (selected)
    Path                      = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
    CLR Version               = v4.0.30319
    MSBuild Version           = v12.0.21005.1
    Windows Phone SDKs        = not installed

Microsoft (R) Windows Phone SDK
  10.0 **Not supported by Titanium SDK 5.2.2.GA**
  8.1 (selected)
 Phone\v8.1\

Windows PowerShell
    Enabled                   = yes
Windows Phone Emulators
Windows Phone Devices

Comment: Still getting

2016-05-11T14:52:03.160Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
No Windows Phone emulators found
2016-05-11T14:52:03.160Z | ERROR  | No Windows Phone emulators found

Comment: Titanium SDK 5.2.2.GA does not support Windows phone sdk 10 supports only 8.1. Titanium SDK 5.4.0(Still in beta) will support 10.