# Windows Emulators in Appcelerator

Tags: windows-mobile, appcelerator

I'm trying to create an app for Windows Mobile using appcelerator, the iOS and Android versions are already build. But I can't find any emulators in Appcelerator.

They are working inside Visual studio 2015.

So I have enabled the Hyper-V options and got the emulators working in VS 2015, when I run the app using appcelerator it says : Invalid "--device-id" value "8-1-1"

What to do?
Thanks in advance!

When I run "appc info" I get this (note that there are no emulators listed :

```
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 6.1.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2017, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Operating System
  Name                        = Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
  Version                     = 10.0.14393
  Architecture                = 32bit
  # CPUs                      = 8
  Memory                      = 15.9GB

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 4.6.0
  npm Version                 = 2.15.9

Appcelerator CLI
  Installer                   = 4.2.8
  Core Package                = 6.1.0

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.11
  node-appc Version           = 0.2.39

Titanium SDKs
  6.0.1.GA
    Version                   = 6.0.1
    Install Location          = C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.1.GA
    Platforms                 = android, mobileweb, windows
    git Hash                  = 265db0d
    git Timestamp             = 12/20/2016 00:54
    node-appc Version         = 0.2.39

Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
  Not installed

Java Development Kit
  Not found

Genymotion
  Path                        = not found
  Genymotion Executable       = not found
  Genymotion Player           = not found
  Home                        = not found

VirtualBox
  Executable                  = not found
  Version                     = unknown

Android SDK
  Android Executable          = not found
  ADB Executable              = not found
  SDK Path                    = not found

Android NDK
  NDK Path                    = not found
  NDK Version                 = not found

Android Platforms
  None

Android Add-Ons
  None

Android Emulators
  None

Genymotion Emulators
  None

Connected Android Devices
  None

Microsoft (R) Visual Studio
  14.0 (selected)
    Path                      = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\
    CLR Version               = v4.0.30319
    MSBuild Version           = v14.0.25420.1
    Windows Phone SDKs        = not installed

Microsoft (R) Windows Phone SDK
  8.1 (selected)
    Path                      = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\

Windows PowerShell
    Enabled                   = yes

Windows Phone Emulators
8.1
10.0

Windows Phone Devices

Java Development Kit Issues
  ×  JDK (Java Development Kit) not installed.
     If you already have installed the JDK, verify your JAVA_HOME environment variable is correctly
     set.
     The JDK is required for must be manually downloaded and installed from
     http://appcelerator.com/jdk.

Android Issues
  ×  JDK (Java Development Kit) not found.
     If you already have installed the JDK, verify your JAVA_HOME environment variable is correctly
     set.
     The JDK can be downloaded and installed from http://appcelerator.com/jdk.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you run this command and see if that helps.

> appc run -p windows --target wp-emulator --deploy-time development
>   --device-id 8-1-1

Please check this thread as well.
[Unable to run Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator on Titanium Appcelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159942/unable-to-run-windows-phone-8-1-emulator-on-titanium-appcelerator)

Make sure Windows 8.1 emulators listed in the **appc info** output. It looks similar to this.

```
Windows Phone Emulators
8.1
  Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB
    UDID                      8-1-1
  Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch
    UDID                      8-1-2
  Emulator 8.1 WXGA 4.5 inch 
    UDID                      8-1-3 
  Emulator 8.1 720P 4.7 inch 
    UDID                      8-1-4 
  Emulator 8.1 1080P 5.5 inch 
    UDID                      8-1-5 
  Emulator 8.1 1080P 6 inch 
    UDID                      8-1-6
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

This is the error I'm after using your suggestion:
2017-02-26T16:27:07.905Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
No Windows Phone emulators found
2017-02-26T16:27:07.908Z | ERROR  | No Windows Phone emulators found

Comment: hmm..looks like there are no windows phone emulators installed in the system.Even your above *appc info" doesn't show windows 8.1 emulators list.